# Prob. $ 9 $, Sec. $ 23 $ of Munkres’ “Topology”, $ 2^{\text{nd}} $ Ed.: How to show this subspace is connected?

Tags: general-topology

Let $A$ be a proper subset of $X$, and let $B$ be a proper subset of $Y$. If $X$ and $Y$ are connected, how to show that $$\left(X \times Y \right) \setminus \left(A \times B \right)$$ is also connected?

Let $x_0 \in X \setminus A$ and $y_0 \in Y \setminus B$. Then $\{x_0 \} \times Y$, being homeomorphic with $Y$, is connected; and $X \times \{ y_0 \}$, being homeomorphic with $X$, is also connected.

So,  $ \left( \{x_0 \} \times Y \right) \cup \left( X \times \{ y_0 \} \right)$, being the union of two connected subspaces having a point (i.e.  the point  $x_0 \times y_0$) in common, is connected.

And, 
$$\left( X \times Y \right) \setminus \left( A \times B \right) = \left( X \times (Y \setminus B) \right) \cup \left( (X \setminus A) \times Y \right).$$

Am I right?

And if so, then how to proceed from here?

An afterthought:

I've thought a bit and have come up with the following:

For each $x \in X \setminus A$, the subspace $\{x \} \times Y$ is connected and has the point $x \times y_0$ in common with  $ \left( \{x_0 \} \times Y \right) \cup \left( X \times \{ y_0 \} \right)$.

For each $y \in Y \setminus B$, the subspace $X \times \{ y \}$ is connected and has the point $x_0 \times y$ in common with  $ \left( \{x_0 \} \times Y \right) \cup \left( X \times \{ y_0 \} \right)$.

Thus, for each $x \in X \setminus A$ and for each $y \in Y \setminus B$, the subspace $ \left( \{x \} \times Y \right) \cup \left( X \times \{ y \} \right)$ is connected and has a point in common with  $ \left( \{x_0 \} \times Y \right) \cup \left( X \times \{ y_0 \} \right)$.

Now we can also write 
$$\left( X \times Y \right) \setminus \left( A \times B \right) = \bigcup_{x \in X \setminus A, \ y \in Y \setminus B} \left[ \left( \{x \} \times Y \right) \cup \left( X \times \{ y \} \right) \right] \ \cup \ \left[ \left( \{x_0 \} \times Y \right) \cup \left( X \times \{ y_0 \} \right) \right],$$ 
which is connected by vritue of Prob. 3, Sec. 23 in Munkres.

Is this reasoning correct? Is it the most efficient way of proving this fact?

Comment: The second proof you gave should be the correct one.

Comment: @DanielRobert-Nicoud, thanks. But what do you mean by "the second proof"?

Comment: @SaaqibMahmuud: He meant your afterthought.